# What is the most efficient method to delete points?

Tags: python, arcgis-desktop, arcpy, point, overlay

I have a script that takes a point featureclass (FC) through the following workflow:

1. Select points that lie within individual polygons
2. From the selected points within each polygon, randomly subset X% of
   points
3. Merge the selected points from each polygon feature sub-selection
4. Erase the original points with the merged subset and write to a new FC

I am using [`arcpy.Erase_analysis()`](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00080000000m000000) to do the point deletion.

The subset of data I am testing this script on has ~35000 point features.  The point subset that I would like to use as the erase feature has ~3000 point features.  It takes approximately 3-5 minutes to complete processing.  Seeing that I will be scaling this up to a dataset containing ~30 million points, *is there a more efficient method to delete points than by using the* [`arcpy.Erase_analysis()`](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00080000000m000000) *method*?  Perhaps, programmatically deleting points in an editing session?  Or, a method that does not involve writing a new point FC?

Comment: If you write out the FC from the selected points won't the erase be unnecessary?

Comment: What type(s) of geodatabase is your feature class stored in?

Comment: @mikeLdub I need to erase a certain percentage of points within each polygon feature and keep the remaining points that do not intersect with the polygons.

Comment: @PolyGeo ESRI FGDB

Comment: Is the selection polygon in step 1 the same as the erase polygon in step 4?  Also, if you have ArcGIS for Desktop Standard or Advanced licensing level then the [**Erase Point**](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001v00000009000000) tool may be worth looking at.

Comment: You could use arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management() or arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management() tools to select the points you want to delete - then use the arcpy.Delete_management() tool to actually delete them, I believe this will be a bit faster than Erase - but definitely not super fast on a 30million point dataset.

Answer (score 4):

You *can't* efficiently delete large numbers of features from a large table, period.

You'd be much better off just marking them as deleted (available varchar(1), values 'Y' or 'N') and adding an attribute constraint to your selection logic (or using a view).  Building a parallel table to house a foreign key and available field is an adequate solution, though the join performance is likely to drag down processing on larger tables.

Be sure to use "Y" and "N" values, rather than nulls, because changing a 1-character value to another 1-character value isn't going to have the same fragmentation impact as changing a null to a string.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not NEED to delete the points, then you could just use the Select By Attribute tool, select the points that you don't need, switch selection and create a new feature class.  That will help your data maintain its original integrity also.